# Getting return Value [object Object] for dropdown at first result. It changes when i select an option and works. How to fix the default result

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, api, object

I have an angular 7 application. I have called services to fetch mysql data. In a form I want to populate a dropdown and want to validate it. But the dropdown always has an undefined value at first so i cannot validate it with required. Why does it have an [object Object] at first? But it works when i properly select a value.

I have used it in a component and works great using the code below

```js
Component.ts file

this.employeeservice.retrieveAllTodos().subscribe(
  response => {
    this.employeesList = response;
    console.log("it works");
  }
);
```

```html
<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" [class.ng-invalid]="!ecode.value" name="ecode" #ecode="ngModel" required [ngModel]="ecode" (ngModelChange)="getId($event,ecode.value)">

  <option *ngFor="let todo of employeesList" value={{todo.employeeCode}}>{{todo.employeeCode}} - {{todo.employeeName}}</option>

</select>
<div *ngIf="ecode.errors && (ecode.dirty || ecode.touched || todoForm1.submitted)">

  <div *ngIf="ecode.errors.required">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Please select code</small>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="ecode.invalid">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Please select code1</small>
  </div>


</div>

<pre> {{ecode.value}}</pre>
<pre *ngIf="ecode.value === null">no value</pre>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWX73.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/reFav.jpg

I have included 2 pictures of my situation

Comment: Because you're setting the value to ecode and that's an object, you have to drill down into that object to display the wanted value. Please add a sample response, this will help identify the structure needed for your form.

Comment: Also this `<pre *ngIf="ecode.value === null">no value</pre>` should just be `<pre *ngIf="!ecode.value">no value</pre>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. setting the ngModel to ecode.value worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this `"[ngModel]="ecode""` looks like ecode is an object

Change this to `"[ngModel]="ecode.value""`.It should work